# Clustering data points based on edge strength

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm looking at a Computer Vision application where I try to analyze the strength of edges a certain set of colors make with another color. For, this I take images of two colors falling on top of each other and record the edge strength (the normalized value I get through Canny edge detection) for a pair of colors.

Now, if I plot this edge strength graph for each color pair I get a graph like below:

[image: edge pair vs edge strength]

In the graph each point represents an edge strength between two colors, which are represented by strings with two RGB tuples.

Based on this edge strength data I'd like to cluster the colors used into a k number of clusters (k is known but arbitrary). The clusters should group the colors such that the color pairs with low edge strength are grouped together, and color pairs that with high edge strength end up in different clusters. For example, if white and yellow have high edge strength, I want them to be in different clusters. If white and grey have low edge strength, I want them in the same cluster. Even though the data is between color pairs, I'd like to get a result where the cluster consists of a set of colors.

I thought this was straight forward with k means clustering, but since the data for color pairs and edge strength between two pairs, I cannot understand how to pre-process the data so that I can cluster the data and get colors as per my requirement. May I know how can I solve my problem with k-means or any other method?

EDIT: I have done smoothing, segmentation on my own before applying edge detection. Without this there's simply too much noise for edge detection. I have applied edge detection in each channel, and normalized and added them to get a strong edge. This all works nicely, and although it alters the original colors, which cannot be helped, it gives decent results that is shown in the graph.

ANOTHER EDIT: The effects of the real world (albedo, incident angle) changes the color a lot. Actually, getting the color values separately and calculating the color values does not give the actual resultant color that occurs when a color falls on the other.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-means clustering uses the value of each observation, not the relationships between them. So, if you want to cluster the data in the form you have it you could use some other clustering method that takes pairwise relationships as an input. [Hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) can be one example. Another method that can be implemented in a way that accepts pairwise proximity matrix is [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN)

If you could understand the law by which edge strengths depends on the color values, you could possibly obtain the absolute positions of the color in some coordinate space and cluster by that with k-means. For example, if you'd measure the strengths as euclidian distance in RGB - you could simply do k-means by RGB values of the colors. But looking at your data, seems like your edge strengths is not proportional to RGB euclidian distance.

Comment: Consider attaching links in a comment or make answer more detailed.

Comment: marol, my answer sort of contains a link to a clustering method that can handle the type of data the asker wants to cluster. What other info would you expect to see here?

Comment: Generally I would expect answers on SO to be more detailed. Of course this link is useful, but why do not put it as a comment under the question? Or extend the answer to contain more information other that a link.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Yes, I should've post it as a comment.

Comment: HAC seems to work nicely. I got it working in matlab. Do you know whether openCV hierarchical clustering also supports this type of similarity data without absolute values?

Comment: According to the doc, seems like no, it unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: Great @vzaguskin, thanks for expanding an answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, canny detector is usually performed on grayscale images. If you are using some library like opencv, your rgb image is most likely converted under the hood.

I assume that when you say "edge strength between two colors" you think of it like half of an image is one color and the other half is the other color. If you only want the strength of an edge in such an image, you don't need the direction of the edge. You don't need the image either. The strength of the edge is just the difference of two intensities which is nice because you can use k-means if your distance metric is transitive.

If you have the rgb colors, just convert them to grayscale and group them up with k-means.

Another thing is, if you use canny from a library it may be applying some smoothing before calculating the strengths which may not be desired for you.

Comment: Actually, I have already done some of what you said. I didn't include details as it will digress from the actual problem. I will add an edit.